# Are non-increasing absolutely continuous functions dense in non-increasing, $L^1([a,b])$ functions?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, measurable-functions, absolute-continuity

I'd like to know whether the set of non-increasing absolutely continuous function is dense in the space of non-increasing functions in $L^1([a,b])$, equipped with the metric $d(f,g)=\int_{[a,b]}\vert f(x)-g(x)\vert dx$.

Most proofs I have seen about density in $L^1$ involves using polynomials but they are not necessarily non-increasing, and it is unclear to me how to modify them to preserve density.

Any hint or reference is welcomed.

Comment: The set of non-increasing functions is a rather unusual set to consider. Do you really mean functions that are not increasing? This would include $\sin x,$ for example.

Comment: This maybe confusing for non native English speakers (like I am): in English non-increasing means *monotonically decreasing*. See [Monotonic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function).

Comment: I mean _monotonically weakly decreasing_. So, I'm not interested in functions like $\sin x$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net: For some reason I'd forgotten that this is fairly standard. After seeing your comment, I first thought that this would only be used along with something like "monotone" so as to exclude functions like $\sin x,$ but apparently [I've used this term quite a bit](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22non-decreasing%22+%22Dave+L+Renfro%22&filter=0). Unless I forget, I think in the future I'll be more careful with the use of "non-increasing" and "non-decreasing", since the word constructions certainly suggest "not increasing" and "not decreasing".

Comment: I'd try to use convolution with a mollifier (smooth kernel). The borders of the interval could add a little amount of technicalities in the proof.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I can tell you that I was confused a lot when I started to do math in English!